# How to use wildcards in filename to attach file to email using python

Tags: python, wildcard

I want to send email with attached jpg file when it is created and then delete the file, leaving no jpg files in the folder. The actual name of the file will change with date and time but I won't know what it is. I tried using this

```
#Email body
rstime = datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%d %b %Y at %H:%M:%S')
body = 'Picture saved of movement at front of house ' + str(rstime)

msg.attach(MIMEText(body, 'plain'))
fp = open('/mnt/usb/motion/*.jpg', 'rb')
img = MIMEImage(fp.read())
fp.close()
msg.attach(img)

#remove file after emailing
os.remove('/mnt/usb/motion/*.jpg')
```

this gives me an error - 
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/mnt/usb/motion/*.jpg'

What is wrong with my code? If I enter the filename it works but I want to use with wildcard.

Comment: You would want to use the `glob` module. Iterate over all files and attach them one by one. The wildcards are not expanded automatically in python (in the way your shell does it for you)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot use the wildcard in this manner. What should happen, if two files would match the wildcard? Should both files be opened in the same object?

You can use the wildcard with e.g. the python `glob` module:

```
import glob
# Email body
rstime = datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%d %b %Y at %H:%M:%S')
body = 'Picture saved of movement at front of house ' + str(rstime)

msg.attach(MIMEText(body, 'plain'))
files = glob.glob("/mnt/usb/motion/*.jpg")
firstFile = files[0]
fp = open(firstFile, "rb");
img = MIMEImage(fp.read())
fp.close()
msg.attach(img)

# remove file after emailing
os.remove(firstFile)
```

Comment: works a treat, while there shouldn't be two files in the folder, this will send the first one and all is ok. thanks

Comment: it'll send the first one, because glob returns a sorted list by default. in your case oldest time stamps will be in the beginning of the list

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [fnmatch](https://docs.python.org/2/library/fnmatch.html)

```
import fnmatch
import os

files = {}
working_dir = '/mnt/usb/motion/'

for filename in fnmatch.filter(os.listdir(working_dir), '*jpg'):
    filepath = os.path.join(working_dir, filename)
    files[filename] = open(filepath).read()
    os.remove(filepath)
```

But the `glob` module looks better though, since you don't have to `join` the file path and the file name in this case.

Comment: yes thanks - I like the glob module suggestion and had been trying it but couldn't get the syntax right. it gives another option so thanks